# Posting JavaScript Value to PHP via Ajax issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to get a value which is from jQuery to PHP so I can do a search function for my site.

I currently have tried:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () { 
   $('#search_button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        carSearch();
   });
});

function carSearch() 
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'cars.php',
        data: 
        {
            mpg : $('.mpg').val()
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("success! "+$('.mpg').val()+"mpg");
        }
    });

}

</script>
```

This ajax is running when the button is pressed and js value is there as it is displayed in the alert.

However

```
if(isset($_POST['mpg']))
                {
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE mpg =< ".($_POST['mpg'])."";
                    echo "<div class='test'></div>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM cars";
                }
```

The isset doesn't trigger, the div is just a big blue box for testing purposes. The ajax is posting to cars.php which is also where the ajax is, so posting to its own file. Which I've not read about being done, but I've posted within the same file before just not with ajax.

I have also tried posting the value from the ajax to another file:

```
<?php
session_start();

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('cdb', $conn);

if(isset($_POST['mpg']))
{
    $r = mysql_query  ("INSERT INTO test VALUES ".($_POST['mpg'])."", $conn);}
}
?>
```

Just to test if it is doing anything and it isn't.

So

```
data: 
        {
            mpg : $('.mpg').val()
        },
```

Appears to be wrong, though I got this from looking at the many many other questions on here to do with passing js to php. I've tried all the variations for it I've seen on here, and only the above code results in the success function alert triggering.

Comment: what is `.mpg` tag? place html code here

Comment: @Farnabaz Its for Miles per Gallon and in the js value is to specify which value I mean as I have 4 jquery objects all holding data, and the variable name for the data they hold would all be the same otherwise..

Comment: does `$('.mpg').val()` return correct value as you want?

Comment: @Farnabaz Yup in the alert it says the right value, just doesn't seem to post to the php.

Comment: @Tom second way seems good, but there is no echo in second way? Also check `var_dump($_POST["mpg"])` in php file in second way

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL tried what you suggested, but still nothing occurs, though I am unsure of the benefit of adding an echo to the other PHP file, as even if the value is posted and isset the echo wouldn't show as its a separate file that I'm not redirecting to. Also the test database table doesn't update so the value isn't getting though :(

Comment: Please do not use mysql_* for new code! Use mysqli oder PDO instead. Be aware of the fact your code is vulnerable for mysql injections.

Comment: Are you sure that your ajax request successfully sent and get response? Check console and see if any error exists

Comment: @Zwirbelbart Thats my uni proff for ya, I'll get on fixing that right away.

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL My site currently has no errors and only 1 warning about "event.returnValue" being deprecated. Also going by user Q17 below for my second attempt the file is being accesses so the ajax is running, plus that the success alert runs.

Answer (score 0):

I see a mistake here

```
$r = mysql_query  ("INSERT INTO test VALUES ".($_POST['mpg'])."", $conn);}
```

The "}" at the end of the line probably throw an error. Is there error in your .php file when the ajax is running ?

To check if there is errors or see what the .php file is returning follow these steps:

1. Using Chrome right click on your page and choose "Inspect Element"
2. Click on "Network" in the menu
3. If not active click on the filter icon (depending on your chrome version)
4. Click on XHR element of submenu
5. Refresh your page and your .php file should appear
6. Click on it and see what the file is returning

(It could also be done in Firefox but not exactly the same titles)

Tell us what you got here.

Also, you should go with the extern file way. Because ajax data returning correspond to the .php file content. If your .php file contains anything else than what you need to return, there is a problem. Example: Any HTML on your .php file will be returning in the ajax data and this is probably far from what you want.

Comment: When I press the button tied to the ajax the file "jsPostTest.php" appears under the XHR tab. I also removed the unnecessary "}" but even when it was present the file was still shown.

Comment: And when you click on "jsPostTest.php" under XHR tab what appear on Response/Preview ? Is there any error ?

Comment: It says the echo and "string(2) "45" Which is the value from the jQuery.

Comment: If you print_r('something') into your "if isset" is this print shown in XHR response ? Maybe also try print_r($_POST) before the if isset, it should return an array with 'mpg' if the post is working.

Comment: Ah yeah, when I have the ajax post the value to the same file nothing actively appears on the page such as the div and echos I tried in the isset, but looking in the XHR the echo/print text is displayed.  When I've done posting to the same file before on another project it would actively update the PHP or make a div (light box) appear, but not now :/

Comment: If you want what is displaying in XHR response to display in your page this has to be done with ajax, in the success method. In fact the jQuery ask .php file some content that is returning to your jQuery and then you can display it. You have to understand that PHP only display content when it is loaded, this is why we use javascript (AJAX) to "cheat"

Comment: In your success function you could start by console.log(data) to see what you get in your console. Then if you want to display data in your page you have to do something similar as data.appendTo('#idofanelement');